# Can I run Ubuntu with VMware?

Tags: vmware

I was looking to install this with or under VMware on windows 7 64bit, is this possible and where can I find instructions on how to do so? I have searched the site and can not find anything for help on installing this with VMware.

Also I have VMware Workstation do I need VMware player?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can =) Actually trying Ubuntu in a virtualized environment is more than encouraged =)

**Resources:**

- [Info on how to install Ubuntu in VMware Player](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/11287/how-to-run-ubuntu-in-windows-7-with-vmware-player/)
- [Info on how to install Ubuntu in VMware Workstation (a little bit outdated)](http://www.sysprobs.com/install-ubuntu-1010-vmware-playerworkstation-working-vmware-tools)
- [A blog post with info on how to install Ubuntu 11.04 on VMware workstation 7](http://linux4everybody.blogspot.gr/2011/04/how-to-install-ubuntu-1104-on-vmware.html)